# Facebook custom share. What is possible?

Tags: php, facebook, share

Hey Guys is it possible to customize an share option?

I am exactly searching for a resolution which allows me to share a specific picture with some text. The picture will change, it depends on what the user recently uploaded.

It is really hard to explain what exactly i am looking for but i'll try.
For example: An User upload a picture of himself on my page. After successful uploading the picture will get some text at the bottom of the picture. After that the user should be able to share this picture on his timeline in Facebook.

Is this realizable??

I am happy on every hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible - you can specify exactly what information is shown with the Share dialog :

Taken from the [FB.ui() documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

As you can see above; You can specify the `name`, `link`, `picture`, `caption` and  `description` parameters of your shared content. 
 You can read at this link more about the Facebook JavaScript SDK :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/